# Erro no código ao compilar

Tags: java

Criei esse código em Java e está dando erro na hora de compilar via CMD:

```
import java.io.*;
import jxl.*;
import java.util.*;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.DateFormat;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.biff.*;
import jxl.write.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class create {
    WritableSheet s = workbook.createSheet("Folha1", 0);
    WritableSheet s1 = workbook.createSheet("Folha1", 0);

    public static void main (String[] args){

        try{
            /*Seta o arquivo e suas instruções de execução*/
            String filename = "test.xls";
            WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
            ws.setLocale (new Locale ("en", "EN"));
            WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename), ws);
            writeDataSheet(s);
            writeImageShet(s1);

            /*Escreve e Fecha o Arquivo*/
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();        

        }
        catch (IOException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        catch (WriteException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    private static void writeDataSheet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{
        /* Formata a Fonte */
        WritavleFont wf = new WritableFont (WritableFont.ARIAL, 10, WritableFont.BOLD);
        WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat (wf);
        cf.setWrap (true);

        /* Cria um Label e Escreve a Data em Uma Célula da Folha */
        Label l = new Label (0,0,"Data",cf);
        s.addCell(l);
        WritableCellFormat cf1 = new WritableCellFormat(DateFormats.FORMAT9);
        DataTime dt = new DateTime(0,1,new Date(), cf1, DateTime.GMT);
        s.adCell(dt);

        /*Cria um Label e Escreve um Float Numver em Uma Célula da Folha*/
        l = new Label(2,0,"Float", cf);
        s.addCell(l);
        WritableCellFormat cf2 = new WritableCellFormat(NumberFormats.FLOAT);
        Number n = new Number(2,2,-3.1415926535, cf2);
        s.addCell(n);
        n = new Number(2,2,-3.1415926535, cf2);
        s.addCell(n);

        /* Cria um label e escreve um float number acima de 3 decimais em uma célula da folha*/
        l = new Label(3,0,"3dps",cf);
        s.addCell(l);
        NumberFormat dp3 = new NumberFormat("#.###");
        WritableCellFormat dp3cell = new WritableCellFormat(dp3);
        n = new Number(3,1,3.1415926535,dp3cell);
        s.addCell(n);

        /* Cria um label e adiciona 2 células na folha*/
        l = new Label(4, 0, "Add 2 cells",cf);
        s.addCell(l);
        n = new Number(4,1,10);
        s.addCell(n);
        n = new Number(4,2,16);
        f = new Formula(4,3, "E1+E2");
        s.addCell(f);

        /* Cria um Label e mulpiplica o valor de uma célula da folha por 2 */
        l = new Label(5,0, "Multiplica por 2",cf);
        s.addCell(l);
        n = new Number(5,1,10);
        s.addCell(n);
        f = new Formula(5,2, "F1 * 3");
        s.addCell(f);

        /* Cria um Label e divide o valor de uma célula da folha por 2.5 */
        l = new Label(6,0, "Divide por 2,5",cf);
        s.addCell(l);
        n = new Number(6,1, 12);
        s.addCell(n);
        f = new Formula(6,2, "F1/2,5");
        s.addCell(f);
        }
    }


    private static void WriteImageShet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{ 
        /* Cria um label e escreve uma imagem em uma célula da folha*/
        Label l = new Label(0, 0, "Imagem");
        s.addCell(l);
        WriteableImage wi = new WriteableImage(0, 3, 5, 7, new File ("imagem.png"));
        s.addCell(wi);

        /* Cria um label e escreve hyperlink em uma célula da folha*/
        l = new Label(0,15, "HiperLink");
        s.addCell(l);
        Formula f = new Formula(1, 15, "DevMedia(\"http://www.devmedia.com.br\", " + "\"Portal DevMedia\")");
        s.addCell(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Já li e reli esse código e ainda da erro falando que as variáveis l, f e a todas as linha que tem:

```
f = new Formula("Argumentos"); 
l = new Label("Argumentos");
WriteableImage wi = new WriteableImage(0, 3, 5, 7, new File ("imagem.png"));
```

Em todos da 73 erros todos desse tipo:

> error: cannot find symbol, error: missing method body or declare
>   abstract, error: Number is abstract; cannot be instantiated

no CMD aparece:

> ```
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:5: error: package jxl does not exist
> import jxl.Workbook;
>           ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:6: error: package jxl.write does not exist
> import jxl.write.DateFormat;
>                 ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:7: error: package jxl.write does not exist
> import jxl.write.Number;
>                 ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableSheet s = workbook.createSheet("Folha1", 0);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritableSheet
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableSheet s1 = workbook.createSheet("Folha1", 0);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritableSheet
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
> private static void writeDataSheet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{
>                                     ^
>   symbol:   class WritableSheet
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
> private static void writeDataSheet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{
>                                                            ^
>   symbol:   class WriteException
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
> private static void WriteImageShet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{
>                                     ^
>   symbol:   class WritableSheet
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
> private static void WriteImageShet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{
>                                                            ^
>   symbol:   class WriteException
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:2: error: package jxl does not exist
> import jxl.*;
> ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:9: error: package jxl.write does not exist
> import jxl.write.*;
> ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableSheet s = workbook.createSheet("Folha1", 0);
>                   ^
>   symbol:   variable workbook
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableSheet s1 = workbook.createSheet("Folha1", 0);
>                    ^
>   symbol:   variable workbook
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
> WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
> ^
>   symbol:   class WorkbookSettings
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
> WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
>                           ^
>   symbol:   class WorkbookSettings
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename), ws);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritableWorkbook
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename), ws);
>                             ^
>   symbol:   variable Workbook
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:29: error: non-static variable s cannot be referenced from a static context
> writeDataSheet(s);
>                ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:30: error: non-static variable s1 cannot be referenced from a static context
> writeImageShet(s1);
>                ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
> catch (WriteException e){
>        ^
>   symbol:   class WriteException
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:52: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
> private static void writeDataSheet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{
>                     ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
> WritavleFont wf = new WritableFont (WritableFont.ARIAL, 10, WritableFont.BOLD);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritavleFont
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
> WritavleFont wf = new WritableFont (WritableFont.ARIAL, 10, WritableFont.BOLD);
>                       ^
>   symbol:   class WritableFont
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
> WritavleFont wf = new WritableFont (WritableFont.ARIAL, 10, WritableFont.BOLD);
>                                     ^
>   symbol:   variable WritableFont
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
> WritavleFont wf = new WritableFont (WritableFont.ARIAL, 10, WritableFont.BOLD);
>                                                             ^
>   symbol:   variable WritableFont
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat (wf);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat (wf);
>                             ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
> Label l = new Label (0,0,"Data",cf);
> ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
> Label l = new Label (0,0,"Data",cf);
>               ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf1 = new WritableCellFormat(DateFormats.FORMAT9);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf1 = new WritableCellFormat(DateFormats.FORMAT9);
>                              ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf1 = new WritableCellFormat(DateFormats.FORMAT9);
>                                                 ^
>   symbol:   variable DateFormats
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
> DataTime dt = new DateTime(0,1,new Date(), cf1, DateTime.GMT);
> ^
>   symbol:   class DataTime
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
> DataTime dt = new DateTime(0,1,new Date(), cf1, DateTime.GMT);
>                   ^
>   symbol:   class DateTime
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
> DataTime dt = new DateTime(0,1,new Date(), cf1, DateTime.GMT);
>                                                 ^
>   symbol:   variable DateTime
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
> l = new Label(2,0,"Float", cf);
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf2 = new WritableCellFormat(NumberFormats.FLOAT);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf2 = new WritableCellFormat(NumberFormats.FLOAT);
>                              ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat cf2 = new WritableCellFormat(NumberFormats.FLOAT);
>                                                 ^
>   symbol:   variable NumberFormats
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:74: error: Number is abstract; cannot be instantiated
> n = new Number(2,2,-3.1415926535, cf2);
>     ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
> l = new Label(3,0,"3dps",cf);
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
> NumberFormat dp3 = new NumberFormat("#.###");
> ^
>   symbol:   class NumberFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
> NumberFormat dp3 = new NumberFormat("#.###");
>                        ^
>   symbol:   class NumberFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat dp3cell = new WritableCellFormat(dp3);
> ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
> WritableCellFormat dp3cell = new WritableCellFormat(dp3);
>                                  ^
>   symbol:   class WritableCellFormat
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
> l = new Label(4, 0, "Add 2 cells",cf);
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:88: error: no suitable constructor found for Double(int,int,int)
> n = new Double(4,1,10);
>     ^
>     constructor Double.Double(double) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>     constructor Double.Double(String) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:90: error: no suitable constructor found for Double(int,int,int)
> n = new Double(4,2,16);
>     ^
>     constructor Double.Double(double) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>     constructor Double.Double(String) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
> f = new Formula(4,3, "E1+E2");
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Formula
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
> l = new Label(5,0, "Multiplica por 2",cf);
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:97: error: no suitable constructor found for Double(int,int,int)
> n = new Double(5,1,10);
>     ^
>     constructor Double.Double(double) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>     constructor Double.Double(String) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
> f = new Formula(5,2, "F1 * 3");
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Formula
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
> l = new Label(6,0, "Divide por 2,5",cf);
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:105: error: Number is abstract; cannot be instantiated
> n = new Number(6,1, 12);
>     ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
> f = new Formula(6,2, "F1/2,5");
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Formula
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:114: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
> private static void WriteImageShet (WritableSheet s)throws WriteException; {{
>                     ^
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
> l = new Label(0, 0, "Imagem");
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
> WriteableImage wi = new WriteableImage(0, 3, 5, 7, new File ("imagem.png"));
> ^
>   symbol:   class WriteableImage
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
> WriteableImage wi = new WriteableImage(0, 3, 5, 7, new File ("imagem.png"));
>                         ^
>   symbol:   class WriteableImage
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
> l = new Label(0,15, "HiperLink");
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Label
>   location: class create
> Controle_Principal_CSG_teste.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
> f = new Formula(1, 15, "DevMedia(\"http://www.devmedia.com.br\", " + "\"Portal DevMedia\")");
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Formula
>   location: class create
> 61 errors
> ```

Comment: não precisa se desculpar existem diversos posts gigantescos e todos com a mesma finalidade, a ideia é aprender, lembrando que quanto mais informação tiver sobre o que você está fazendo melhor, é mais simples de identificar os erros

Comment: `n = new Number(3,1,3.1415926535,dp3cell);` isso ta errado, Number não é um tipo instanciavel. Você precisa escolher se é Double, Float, Integer. Number nao pode.

Comment: Troquei os que tavão com os números com . tipo o que vc boto acima 3.14159... reduzio os erros agora tem 61 agora so ta com erros no que tem o new Label e o new Formula

Comment: Não da pra saber se você não mostrar os erros e onde eles ocorrem. Edite a pergunta e forneça mais informações.

Comment: pode postar oque ta aparecendo no cmd?

Comment: Sim, mas adicione na pergunta, clicando em EDITAR.

Comment: Foi abandondado '-'

Comment: @BitsofBytes Vim te salvar

Comment: @LINQ consegue entender oque ta dando o erro?

Comment: @BitsofBytes Sim e já respondi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, veja o que o erro diz:

> abstract, error: **Number is abstract; cannot be instantiated**

O que tá acontecendo aí é um conflito entre as classes [**`jxl.write.Number`**](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/Number.html) e [**`java.lang.Number`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

Eu julgo que você queira usar a primeira delas, até porque nem faria sentido usar a outra uma vez que ela é uma **classe abstrata**.

Como todas as classes de `java.lang` estão implicitamente importadas em todo o projeto, você vai precisar escrever o nome completo da classe de `jxl.write`.

Por exemplo:

```
n = new Number(2,2,-3.1415926535, cf2);
```

Comment: esse do number foi resolvido vlw pela ajuda so falta resolver o do Label

Comment: Ótimo. Abra uma nova pergunta com o novo problema. O site preza por tópicos bem definidos

Comment: o problema já ta mencionado la em cima mais ok to no ônibus indo para casa agora quando chegar vo arrumar o código no pc e fazer o novo tópico vlw pela ajuda.